# VS Code Microsoft Edge Developer tools not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, developer-tools

I was very eager to try out the Microsoft Edge Developer Tools Plugin for VS Code...

I installed the extension, and when I went to launch it VSCode gives the error message:

"Microsoft Edge could not be found. Ensure you have installed Microsoft Edge and that you have selected 'default' or the appropriate version of Microsoft Edge in the extension settings panel."

I do have 'default' selected. And have tried searching around for a solution.
No luck yet... I'd appreciate any advice... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend providing more information about the issue you're experiencing so others can test and try to replicate it. There are multiple Microsoft Edge tools in the VS Code Marketplace, so providing a link to the one you're trying to use is advisable. Additionally, it's helpful to provide the version of MS Edge and VS Code you currently have installed.

That said, assuming you're trying to use [Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools), [the documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-edge-devtools/index) says, "This extension only supports Microsoft Edge (version greater than 80.0.361.48)".

Thus, I'd recommend you start troubleshooting by making sure both your Microsoft Edge **and** VS Code are updated to the most recent versions.

If that doesn't fix the issue, please provide more details about your setup - potentially including screenshots - that can help to diagnose the issue.